# OnClick renders the result at second click

Tags: reactjs, onclick

With this onClickHandler I check the input values and if everything is ok (isValid true) so I put the result in the component.

Everything work but at the second click on the button

```
function submitBtn(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          
            CheckDay(dayInput.day);
            checkMonth(monthInput.month);
            checkYear(yearInput.year);
          
            if (yearInput.year && monthInput.month && dayInput.day && 
                yearInput.isValid && monthInput.isValid && dayInput.isValid) {
                    resultYears(yearInput.year);
                    resultMonths(monthInput.month);
                    resultDays(dayInput.day);
            } else {
                setResults({ years: undefined, months: undefined, days: undefined });
            }
          }
```

```
<Result 
        tot={results.years ? results.years : '--'}
        type="years" />
        
        <Result 
        tot={results.months ? results.months : '--'}
        type="months" />
        <Result 
        tot={results.days ? results.days : '--'}
        type="days" />
```

I tried with async/await and nothing changed

Comment: please, provide more code to solve your problem. For example, how and where you attached you submit function, what does resultYears function do and so on. Without these information it’s hard to answer you